# How to Count Predicate Expressions

Tags: c#, .net

I got a GenericEntity and below is the code

```
private Expression<Func<GenericEntity, bool>>GetGenericEntitySearchExpression(GenericEntityParameter searchParameter)
{
   var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<GenericEntity>();
   if (searchParameter.RegionCode == 1)
   {
       predicate = predicate.And<GenericEntity>(e => e.RegionCode == searchParameter.RegionCode);
   }

   if (searchParameter.CountryCode > 0)
   {
        predicate = predicate.And<GenericEntity>(e => e.CountryCode == searchParameter.CountryCode);
   }
}
```

The GetGenericEntitySearchExpression() returns expression. Is there a way to know how many expressions got appened as you can see from the code the depending on the condtion it will append the condition

Answer (score 1):

You can create an expression visitor to count the number of expressions matching a predicate:

```
public class Counter : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private Func<Expression, bool> predicate;
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public Counter(Func<Expression, bool> predicate)
    {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (predicate(node))
            Count++;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static int Count(
    this Expression expression, 
    Func<Expression, bool> predicate)
{
    var counter = new Counter(predicate);
    counter.Visit(expression);
    return counter.Count;
}
```

And then just count the number of `And` expressions.

```
var numberOfAnds = expression.Count(ex => ex.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @servy for the tip. I used a Generic class instead of inheriting. There may be even better approach than the code mentioned below

```
private ExpressionWithCounter<GenericEntity> GetGenericEntitySearchExpression(GenericEntityParameter searchParameter)
{
    var expressionCounter = new ExpressionWithCounter<GenericEntity>();
    expressionCounter.Predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<GenericEntity>();

    if (searchParameter.RegionCode == 1)
    {
    expressionCounter.Append(expressionCounter.Predicate.And<GenericEntity>(e => e.RegionCode == searchParameter.RegionCode));
    }

    if (searchParameter.CountryCode > 0)
    {
        expressionCounter.Append(expressionCounter.Predicate.And<GenericEntity>(e => e.CountryCode == searchParameter.CountryCode));
    }
}


public class ExpressionWithCounter<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Predicate;
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Append(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        Predicate = expression;
        Count++;
    }
}


ExpressionWithCounter<GenericEntity> whereExperssion = GetGenericEntitySearchExpression(searchParameter);

//Is Any expression added?
if(whereExperssion.Count > 0)
{
    //Perform any action
}
```

Comment: If you're going to modify the source of the method itself there's no real need for all of this complexity, just increment a counter whenever you add a new condition.  There's no real need for this other class.

Comment: There are nearly 20 IF ELSE conditions in my actual code so I found this way of handling is better. My solution might not be the best but it solves my issue

Comment: If there are a whole bunch of conditions that's a point against using this approach entirely.  My approach requires no manipulation of the method at all, leaving nothing to update at all.  That said; I don't see how calling this method of yours is really less work than adding a `count++;` line to each block.